# WPF DataGrid bind data between columns

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagridview, datagrid

Lets say I have 2 columns in my data Grid: Column A: Selected, and Column B: Name. The Selected column is a checkbox. And Name column is text field. I want to set the color of the text in 'Name' column as Blue if Column A's check box is checked, and Red otherwise.

Essentially I don't know how to bind data between columns of the datagrid. And sample code/link providing example would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used the [WPF Toolkit's DataGrid](http://wpf.codeplex.com/) much, but from what I can gather, one method is to use DataGridTemplateColumn's and then set up your [DataTriggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx) based on the binding.

Here is an example that uses DataTriggers to set the style of the Foreground color as well the entire row's background color. Of note, you'll need a boolean Property in your ItemsSource's binding to make this work with this method.

**XAML**

```
<Window.Resources>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type tk:DataGridRow}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger 
            Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="MyTextBlockStyle">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger 
            Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger 
            Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>


</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
<tk:DataGrid x:Name="MyGrid" 
             AutoGenerateColumns="False"
             ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <tk:DataGrid.Columns>

        <tk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Selected"
                                   Width="75">
            <tk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                     <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </tk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </tk:DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <tk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="100" >
            <tk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" 
                               Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlockStyle}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </tk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </tk:DataGridTemplateColumn>   

    </tk:DataGrid.Columns>
</tk:DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class DataGridDataTrigger : Window
{
    public List<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DataGridDataTrigger()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var names = new List<string> { "Joe", "Bob", "Frank", "Scott", "Mike" };
        People = new List<Person>();
        names.ForEach( x => People.Add( new Person { Name = x } ) );

        People.ForEach( x =>
                           {
                               if( x.Name.Contains( "o" ) )
                                   x.IsSelected = true;
                           } );

        MyGrid.DataContext = People;
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```